# How to calculate the viscous damping coefficient of a viscous layer between an inner sphere and an enclosing outer sphere?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, friction, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity, viscosity

In [this article](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdf/10.2514/3.20705) by Rahn and Barba, a flat-spin transition manoeuvre is investigated. For this it is assumed that a rigid spacecraft contains a spherical, dissipative fuel slug of inertia $\boldsymbol{J}$, which is surrounded by a viscous layer. The coupled equations of motion are given as:

$$\mu \boldsymbol{\sigma} + {\boldsymbol{T}} = \left( \boldsymbol{I} - \boldsymbol{J} \right) \dot{\boldsymbol{\omega}} + \boldsymbol{\omega}  \times \boldsymbol{I} \boldsymbol{\omega}$$

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{\sigma}} = -\dot{\boldsymbol{\omega}} - \boldsymbol{J}^{-1}\left(\mu \boldsymbol{\sigma}\right) - \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{\sigma}$$

where $\boldsymbol{I}$ is the inertia tensor of the spacecraft *including* the slug, $\boldsymbol{T}$ is the torque about the principal axes, $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is the angular velocity of the spacecraft, $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is the angular velocity of the slug relative to the spacecraft, and finally, $\mu$ is the so-called *viscous damping coefficient* of the fuel slug in [Nms]. This is also the unit of *angular impulse*.

**NB:** I'm not sure as to whether this definition is actually accurate, as in for example [this article](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1687814016643068), the viscous damping coefficient is measured in [Ns/m].

In the article, $\mu=30$ [Nms]. However, no explanation is provided about how this coefficient was determined. Hopefully someone here has a clue.

**Question:** How does one calculate the viscous damping coefficient of a viscous layer between an inner solid sphere and an enclosing outer hollow sphere (see cross-section below)?

[image]